# how to import rules from master rules file

Tags: jboss, drools

I have rules file (.drl) with almost 100 rules. However I want to give user the flexibility to chose what rules to be effective at any point.
I am thinking if there is a way to import the desired rules into separate .drl file, so that user can pick and chose the rules

Is it possible to import rules of one .drl file into other .drl file? If no, how can I ensure that user will have option to chose/pick the rules that are going to be effective at any point.

Also having 100 rules in one file is not effective and referring them with single line/name would be readable.

Hints pl?

Comment: Why do you say "having 100 rules in one file is not effective"? 100 rules isn't much.

Comment: All the rules are lumped in one file now and they are sort of unrelated. I want to separate out those rules into different .drl files based on business areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "import" for rules from one DRL into another DRL.

What to do tosolve your problem depends on the required granularity of rule selection.

If there is a small number N of static combinations you might build N rule bases and let users select a rule base. This is clean and controlled and testable.

If there is a number of *disjoint* sets, use agenda groups. A user selects the agenda group, and only the rules in that group are active. (If the sets are not disjoint, you could still use agenda groups, at the cost of duplicating rules using different names for occurrence in different agenda groups. Ugly, not recommended.)

For arbitrary dynamic selection, you'll have to devise some mechanism. For instance:

```
rule "rule1"
when
    Select( name == "rule1" )
    All( ... )
    Original( ... )
    Patterns( ... )
then ... end
```

Insertion of a new Select( "rule1" ) selects, retracting retracts. Depending on the way selections should be made, you can also implement "features":

```
rule "rule x" # part of feature f1 and f2
when
    Select( featureSet contains Feature.f1 || Feature.f2 )
    All( ... )
    Original( ... )
    Patterns( ... )
then ... end
```

You can write rules to check feature combinations, e.g.

```
rule "feature check"
when
    Select( featureSet contains Feature.black && Feature.white )
then
    ... cant have black *and* white at the same time ...
end
```

Comment: can you point me to some literature or examples on select/all/original/patterns. I used when/then/end and nothing beyond that.

Comment: Select is a class you'll have to define. All/Original/Pattern is meant as a stand-in for what you haven't posted, i.e., the contents of your rule.